# OOPHP inheritance query

Tags: php, oop, inheritance

as far as I understand, a `private` member can only be accessed inside the class that owns it, and not outside, even from children of that class.

I wrote a little test script to try to help firm all this up in my head, but it doesn't output an error, accessing the `private` member fine, and I have no idea why!!  Please can someone help me with this?

here's the code:

```
        class Car extends vehicle
        {
            protected $make;

            public function showCar($col, $eng, $mak)
            {
                $this->colour = $col;
                $this->engine = $eng;
                $this->make = $mak;

                $this->details($this->colour, $this->engine, $this->make);
            }  
        }    

        class vehicle
        {
            private $colour;
            protected $engine;

            public function details($c, $e, $m)
            {
                echo "{$c} {$e} {$m}";
            }

        }

        $output = new Car;
        $results = $output->showCar("red", "v12", "ferarri");
```

Comment: Aside: a method `showCar` that sets properties is misnamed, since it is a setter as well.

Comment: +1 for Object Oriented Programming of Hypertext Processor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is incorrect. `Car::showCar` does *not* set the value of `vehicle::$colour`; it sets a (public) property named `colour` on the object that anyone can access. That's how PHP works: you are not strictly required to declare properties (and hence their accessibility level); you can create and use them on the fly.

To see that this is indeed the case, change the code so that `details` is not fed the relevant values directly but pulls them out of the object on its own:

```
public function showCar($col, $eng, $mak)
{
    $this->colour = $col; // creates a new public property named "colour"
    $this->engine = $eng; // sets vehicle::$engine
    $this->make = $mak;   // sets car::$make

    $this->details();
}  

public function details()
{
    echo "{$this->colour} {$this->engine} {$this->make}";
}
```

In this implementation of `details`, the reference to `$this->engine` resolves to `vehicle::$engine` because that property has been formally declared. Since `showCar` did *not* assign a value to that property you will not see "red" in the output. If you then removed the declaration `private $colour` entirely then `$this->colour` would resolve to the dynamically created property and the program would revert back to its original behavior.

Comment: To see what you ended up with, `var_dump($output);`. You'll find `public $colour` for the implicitly declared public property